# Size constraints for Qt layouts

Tags: qt, qt5, qlayout

My widget has two layouts. The main layout is `outerLayout`, and it should always occupy the entire widget. This contains a `QLabel` and a second layout named `innerLayout`.

`innerLayout` should be centered inside `outerLayout` and it should only be large enough to contain its widgets. I've set size constraints for both layouts, but in the following code, `innerLayout` expands to fill `outerLayout`.

```
outerLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
outerLayout->addWidget(label);
outerLayout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMaximumSize);
innerLayout = new QGridLayout();
innerLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
innerLayout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
outerLayout ->addLayout(innerLayout);
setLayout(outerLayout);
```

If I set the size constraint for both layouts to `SetFixedSize`, both layouts will be reduced to their minimum size. But I want the outer layout to occupy the entire space and the inner layout to use the minimum possible space. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use spacers  as extra widgets of outerlayout. In other words: the spacers will be siblings of innerlayout and will push inner layout to it's minimal needed surface. You will need horizontal and vertical spacers.